# Eloquent Collection contains() work but diff() or intersect() thinks all are different

Tags: php, laravel, collections, eloquent

I have an array of strings that helps me to initiate and `find()` the related models.

```
$arr = [
   "App\Post"  => 1,
   "App\Video" => 1
];
// this array is [Model => ModelId]
```

At this point, I am initiating model class from string and using `find()` to find the model object.

I also have 2 relationships of `morphByMany()` in my User model that returns me a collection of both.

```
// class User
public function entities() {
  // this returns merged collection successfully
  return ($this->videos)->merge($this->posts);
}
```

---

At this point, if I try with `contains()`, **it works**:

```
foreach ($arr as $modelString => $modelId) {
     // this finds the related model:
     $model = $modelString::find($modelId)->first(); 

     $this->entities()->contains($model); // returns true
}
```

---

However, if I try to create a new collection based on my initiated models, `$collection->diff($collection2)` or `$collection->intersect($collection)` **doesn't work**.

```
$collection1 = $this->entities();
$collection2 = collect();

foreach ($arr as $modelString => $modelId) {
     $model = $modelString::find($modelId)->first(); 

     $collection2->push($model);
}

$collection1->diff($collection2); // returns all items
$collection1->intersect($collection2); // returns []

// intersect() and diff() should be other way around
```

---

(Just to clear, both `$this->entities()` and `$arr` have same models. The only difference is `$this->entities()` return pivot values along with the model whereas the ones initiated from `$arr` doesn't; however `contains()` work.

Comment: I can't replicate this. What version of Laravel you on?

Comment: Can you share the database migrations and factories?

Comment: It's pretty complicated to put all migrations there, however I believe the problem lies that the `entities()` collection has models with relationships but other ones doesn't

Comment: Yes they are considered different. Are you sure contains returns true?

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this on the latest version of Laravel and I can't replicate the part where you mention `->contains` returns `true`. I get `false` when I try the `contains` like you do, which is the expected behaviour because a model with relationship and another model without the relationship is considered different.

You could use the function `diffUsing` to pass a callback to check if the class and the id of the item is the same or not.

```
$c1->diffUsing($c2, function ($a, $b) {
    return get_class($a) != get_class($b) || $a->id != $b->id;
});
```

Comment: I couldn't make this work either for some reason even though it makes sense. Do `diffUsing()` care about the orderings - that may be the issue. But I made it work with unsettingRelation - thanks for the tip "because a model with relationship and another model without the relationship is considered different.". Take a look in my answer

Comment: I had better results using as return of diffUsing callback, a int value, can be a distance in diference between the two objects like `$a->id - $b->id` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

@Chin Leung's "a model with relationship and another model without the relationship is considered different." gave me the way to think in a different approach.

```
$collection1 = $this->entities()->map(function($item) {
    return $item->unsetRelation('pivot');
});
```

And then, `diff()` and `intersect()` started working as expected!